# What does AuthenticablePrincipal.RefreshExpiredPassword() do?

Tags: active-directory

I'm looking for an example scenario where this function could be used. MSDN documentation is non-existent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in theory, it resets the age of the user's password to zero. You'd use it if for whatever reason you had a policy mandating passwords to be changed after a certain interval, but in some cases (certain users, maybe?) you wanted to let them keep their passwords longer.