# Extending, or refreshing, expired password in AD

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

In Active Directory, there is a property to hold when an account's password will expire. I want to refresh this date to something like DateTime.Now, so that the current password still can be logged in to the domain with, but the following code is not working for me:

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "someUser");

user.RefreshExpiredPassword();
```

According to [what does UserPrincipal.RefreshExpiredPassword() update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206479/what-does-userprincipal-refreshexpiredpassword-update) , the refresh method sets `pwdLastSet` to -1, but it doesn't seem to work for me. When looking in the AD, the same date as before is still set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow with `user.Save();`